# Logstash high availability deployment

Tags: linux, logging, logstash, high-availability, failover

I am using [logstash](http://logstash.net/) in a mode where it reads log files from disk and puts in ElasticSearch.

What is the best way to deploy logstash for high availability (especially failover)? I'm ok with both active/active mode where two logstash instances are always active, and with active/passive mode where one instance is working and the other one will start only if the first one is down.

I'm specifically asking about logstash and not ElasticSearch.

Comment: I think you may calculate the cost of such a deployment. If logs are so important that you must deploy HA for logstash, you’d better choose some other solutions with high availability. Say, maybe Kafka included. If you just deploy this for testing, then no extra information. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that Logstash does not have built in HA options, where we remain with Linux classic - Virtual IP. I was thinking on the same topick, and currently decided to try the following option (hot/cold version):

- build 2 separate server instances with Logstash as indexer
- find a way, to sync .conf files of Logstash indexer (rsync, git, etc.)
- use Virtual IP solution and Linux heartbeat, to move active Virtual IP between servers or use other load balancing solution, which could act as such (for example, pfsense as load balancer)
- each Logstash indexer instance has it's own REDIS instance, to keep a buffer of logs, and potentially allow to move logs from buffer, if something goes wrong with Logstash.

Here are issues, that need to be solved out, yet:

- Redis can not be run in HA active/active, which introduce issue of log message routing and finding during or after instance switch.
- The same with Active/Passive Logstash, when switching occurs - how to get missing logs within this timeframe.

As far as I know, Active/Active Logstash is available only with the following options taken in mind:

- logs are doubled. If you put both indexer nodes for output in Logstash shippers.
- or you have to provide logical mechanism to ship logs on conditions outside Logstash indexer configuration - e.g. figure it out, not to ship the same log messages to both indexers.

Comment: Here is another approach, but this still lacks the way to recover logs lost in transit, while switch over occurs. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/8Km9VFqapig

Answer (score 1):

You could use a queue that will act as a buffer between input and indexing process.

It's always a good thing to separate tier with a queue, so if elasticsearch crashs, your application will not suffer.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to go in this case is to use some sort of hardware balancer, like F5 (in case you have some) pool, so you defined a VIP with the corresponding ports and then you associate that VIP with the N IP addresses of the N logstash hosts, so in that way you could have any amount of nodes from logstash or whatever service you need to run, and then it applied a round-robin algorithm and balance the connections.